# Driving a service API from a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

I get an error message when I attempt to bind from the onReceive() of a receiver to a local service before I drive a bespoke API on it.

"IntentReceiver components are not allowed to bind to services"

What is the best way of getting a piece of data from a service while in a broadcast reciever.

Many thanks.

P.S. I need to get the answer synchronously i.e. I have wait on the answer from the service so a callback may not be possible.

Answer (score 4):

> What is the best way of getting a piece of data from a service while in a broadcast reciever.

If the `BroadcastReceiver` is created from something else (e.g., an activity) and set up with `registerReceiver()`, then the "something else" is what should be binding to the service and doing the work.

If the `BroadcastReceiver` is a component registered in the manifest, then you need to rethink your approach to whatever problem you are trying to solve. These sorts of `BroadcastReceivers` cannot bind to services and cannot spend much time doing work. If the `BroadcastReceiver` cannot do its work in less than, say, 10ms, it should delegate control to a service via `startService()`. That service can then do the work on a background thread.

> P.S. I need to get the answer synchronously i.e. I have wait on the answer from the service

See above.

Comment: Hi, it is the latter. The crazy thing is I am only implementing a service as a vehicle for listening to the signal strength over an extended period of time and setting a member data variable I had hoped would be accessed through a (bound) API. I have no Activities in the app, so nothing else to hang the listener off.

Comment: The BroadcastReceiver is basically the whole app - it sniffs out incoming call state changes and intercepts outgoing call requests. Just before those outgoing requests leave the phone I want to check the signal strength "inline". To do this we had already established that I would need a service just to hold the lifetime of the listener I would need for remembering the last signal strength value. I need that value to be available to me as I execute the code   in the onReceive() for outgoing calls. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @SCG: You're going to be stuck with a static data member, then, updated from the service, read by the `BroadcastReceiver`. In any ordinary application, this should be avoided like the plague.

Comment: That was my conclusion too, ugly as sin but it works. Thanks.

Comment: @CommonsWare We are dealing with broadcast receivers ourselves. Could you elaborate on your proposed solution? *even if it is ugly*